# BigQuery - Cacheing possibly isn't working. How do I diagnose?

Tags: sql, caching, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have a BigQuery query that is triggered via a Google Cloud Endpoints API written in Java, and I've configured the queryJobConfiguration as follows, to use the BigQuery query cache:

```
    // create new big query configuration
    BqEntity entity = new BqEntity();
    entity.queryJobConfiguration = QueryJobConfiguration
            .newBuilder(query)
            .setUseLegacySql(false)
            .setUseQueryCache(true)
            .build();
```

The cacheing doesn't *appear* to be working, and I need to confirm, definitively, whether or not this is really the case. When I re-issue a query by reloading data via the web front end, that results  in an identical query to the last time it was run, I'm seeing no improvement in performance, and the performance issue *appears* to be at the back-end (it could be a number of factors - I want to check first if BigQuery cacheing is an issue).

My question is - how can I check whether cacheing was used for the query? I'm not seeing anywhere in The Google Cloud Console that lets me see which queries have been run, and whether the cache was used (I'm looking for the type of thing that SQL Server Profiler provides, but haven't found that in the Google Cloud Console and haven't found anything after Googling).

Answer (score 1):

> Cacheing possibly isn't working. How do I diagnose?
>   I need to confirm, definitively, whether or not this is really the case

There are two common ways to determine if BigQuery returned a result using the cache:

If you are using the GCP Console or the classic BigQuery web UI, the result string does not contain information about the number of processed bytes, and displays the word "cached".

Cache indicator in the UI

[image]

If you are using [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/), the [cacheHit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobstatistics2) property in the query result is set to true.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail (again), I already know about the feature you're referring to - what I need to do is to determine whether a query *run via the API* is using cacheing. Do you know if there's a way to view queries that have been run programatically and check if cacheing was used?

Comment: Ah, OK I read your answer properly. So I've found a way I can run a query as a `com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job` then use its getStatistics method. That should give me access somehow to the `cacheHit` property you're referring to, thanks. I feel that there should be an easier way to do this!

Comment: Hi @Mikhail. I still haven't found how to access that `cacheHit` property you refer to. I've raised another question for this here, any advice would be great! - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57141083/how-do-i-access-the-cachehit-property-of-my-bigquery-result-set